# What should be the next software version number?

Tags: version-control, versioning

My current live app is 1.2.3.

Internally i have released up to 1.2.3.5 for testing. I now need to do an emergency fix on the production app. this version should ideally be 1.2.4 , but it would be confusing, as it should have all changes upto 1.2.3.5 and it would not.

I cant make the new production app 1.2.3.1 because that was already released internally.

what should be the new version number for my app?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend something akin to `1.2.3 Update 1`. Or, `1.2.3.0.1`, although I personally think more than four version numbers is ugly and would go with the former. FWIW, Java also uses similar wording.

The other logical options collide with existing versions and have a good probability of causing confusion, as you have already pointed out.

---

Ideally I would begun using `1.2.4.x` internally as soon as `1.2.3` was released, thereby reserving the rest of `1.2.3.x` for out-of-band updates to the current production version. You may wish to adopt something like this for the future to avoid similar collisions, but it is truly personal preference.

Comment: if you use 1.2.4.x internally, they would have the same issue when they are going to release a fix to 1.2.4 later.

Comment: @rfsk2010 Maybe I wasn't clear, but this won't happen. When 1.2.4 is released, the next 1.2.4.x numbers would be reserved for fixes and internal numbering moves up immediately to 1.2.5. I've edited my wording slightly to hopefully make this clear.

Comment: let me make it clear, Say 1.2.3 is live. the internal releases are 1.2.4.x . then 1.2.4 goes live. now internal will be 1.2.5.x . if there is now a fix for 1.2.4(live) ,you cannot start off with 1.2.4.1 etc because it was already used up before 1.2.3 went live.

Comment: I must be missing something. In your example, 1.2.3 is live, then internal releases are 1.2.4.x. Then 1.2.4 goes live (let's say the version at that point is 1.2.4.7), and future internal releases now start at 1.2.5.x. Fixes for the live versions would continue numbering from 1.2.4.8

Comment: ok right. the only thing i dont like in this is , that the fix release would jump to 1.2.4.8 even though it was only one bug fix. but the release version has jumped 7 times.

Comment: No, the release version would only jump one number. 1.2.4.7 was the current production version before the fix.